# How to exclude node_modules from IDEA's "TODO" scanning?

Tags: intellij-idea

The IDEA `TODO` tool windows shows me there's 135 "TODO" items in my `frontend/node/node_modules/npm` directory.

I can exclude those TODOs by selecting `Project Production Files` as the scope, but I don't want to set the window to that scope as I often use TODO markers in test code.

The `node_modules` directory is already in my `.gitignore` so I would've thought the TODO window would already ignore those directories.

Is there an easy way to tell IDEA not to show TODOs from the `node_modules` directory?

My current workaround is to change how I write my TODO notes and use a custom filter pattern to only show TODOs matching that pattern.

Using IDEA 2019.2.

Comment: You could create custom scope that excludes "frontend/node/node_modules/npm" directory and use that scope instead of "Project Production Files"

Answer (score 0):

if I write this

```
# dependencies
/node_modules
```

in .gitignore `// TODO text` not showing me.
If you will add `/node_modules` in `.gitignore` I think it will be work.
Anyway, sales@jetbrains.com JetBrains support can help you.